# Pegando ID da div superior ao click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar o ID da DIV superior ao que o botão se encontra, por exemplo:

```
<div id="1">
  <button id="1"></button>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <button id="2"></button>
</div>
```

Se eu clicar no botão 2 ele deve informar o nome da div 2, porem o que se torna um problema é que existem varias outras div dentro da div 2, o exemplo real segue abaixo:

```
        <div class="upage hidden background_PRINCIPAL" id="lista_REUNIAO">
        <div class="upage-outer fixed-header-footer">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar inner-element uib_w_37 colorGeral bar-positive bar-header" data-uib="ionic/header" data-ver="0" align-title="center">
                <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col">
                    <button class="button widget uib_w_39 d-margins ion ion-chevron-left" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="btn_Voltar_Minha_Celula"></button>
                </div>
                <h1 class="title">Historico de Reuniões</h1>
                <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col"></div>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <div class="upage-content content-area" id="page_9_17">
                <div id="barSelectAll">
                    <li class="item item-checkbox colorCheck">
                        <label class="checkbox checkbox-dark">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                        </label>
                        <span class="textoSelecionarTodos">Selecionar todos</span>
                    </li>

                </div>
                <ul class="list" id="listaReunioes"></ul>
                <div id="barOption">
                    <div class="button-bar widget uib_w_69 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/button_bar" data-ver="0">
                        <a href="#janela" rel="modal">
                            <button class="button widget uib_w_70 button-assertive ion ion-android-close" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0"></button>
                        </a>
                        <button class="button widget uib_w_71 button-positive ion ion-edit" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="btnAlteraReuniao"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="window" id="janela">
                    <a href="#" class="fechar">
                        <img src="images/icones/close_4-512.png" width="25px" height="25px">
                    </a>
                    <h4>Você tem certeza que deseja deletar esta(s) reuniões ?</h4>
                    <p>Se estiver certo desta decisão oferecemos duas opções para você. Recomendamos a escolha da primeira.</p>
                    <p>A primeira você clica em 'Enviara para Lixeira', esta opção você terá condição de refazer.</p>
                    <p>A segunda você clica em 'Excluir', caso escolha esta opção esteja ciente que não tera como refazer,</p>
                    <p>tudo que estiver ligado a este membro será excluido.</p>
                    <button id="lixeira">Enviar para Lixeira</button>
                    <button id="delCompleto">Excluir</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Preciso disto para dar scrollTOP na div correta segue o que utilizo hoje:

```
   $("a[rel=modal]").click( function(ev){
 ev.preventDefault();
 var body = document.getElementById("page_31_31"); //AQUI TEM QUE SER O ID DA DIV ONDE AQUELE BOTAO SE ENCONTRA
 body.scrollTop = 0;
$(body).animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);

var id = $(this).attr("href");

   var alturaTela = $(body).height();
    var larguraTela = $(window).width();

//colocando o fundo preto
$('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
$('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
$('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ( $(id).height() / 6 );

$(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
$(id).show();   
});
```

Comment: Não podem existir dois ID's com valores iguais em um HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo abaixo usando o `closest` e uma classe definida na `div` pai.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-1").on('click', function(){
    var divId = $(this).closest('div.area').attr('id');
    $("#resultado").text(divId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area" id="rh">
  <button id="btn-1"> Clique Aqui </button>
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando a função `parent()` no jQuery você pega o elemento pai do elemento em questão.

No exemplo abaixo, ao clicar no botão está setando o background da div pai de vermelho.

[Referência](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <button id="1">filho 1</button>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <button id="2">filho 2</button>
</div>
```